# Cannot sign a message with web3js (invalid from address)

Tags: web3js

So I am trying to create a signature of a string, but I cannot do that, as I always get error stating `MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: WalletMiddleware - Invalid "from" address.` (code: -32603). I am creating a message with `window.web3.eth.sign(hash, userAddress)` function, where user address is response of `window.ethereum.enable()` function.

[image: error in chrome console]

Comment: And you didn't find a way to paste it here as plain text?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly you need to paste here? The full error? `code: -32603
message: "Error: WalletMiddleware - Invalid "from" address.↵    at l (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.js:1:1085123)"`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = userAddress;
```

to set the default account