# The object could not be cloned. && DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window'

Tags: web3js, metamask, signature

When I try to sign a message with this simple function `const signatue = await window.web3.eth.sign(hash, userAddress)` I get an error.

In firefox I get `Unhandled promise rejection DOMException: "The object could not be cloned."`

The actual data I put into this function for example are: `hash 0x2339863461be3f2dbbc5f995c5bf6953ee73f6437f37b0b44de4e67088bcd4c2 account_address 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57`

I am using "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.47" and Metamask 6.1.0.

In "1.0.0-beta.46" Iam getting error I have already mentioned there [Cannot sign a message with web3js (invalid from address)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67677/cannot-sign-a-message-with-web3js-invalid-from-address?noredirect=1#comment81681_67677)

In beta "^1.0.0-beta.37" everything works fine.

Please help me :(

The same error in chrome

````
              if (!error) {
                resolve(response);
              }
   ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
    at i._write (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:114976)
    at b (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:133822)
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:136934
    at i.g.write (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:136961)
    at e.exports.y (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:126211)
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:37123
    at e.exports.s.emit (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:37193)
    at w (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:121050)
    at _ (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:120865)
    at e.exports.b.push (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:121676)```
````